# Why is the minimum windows size rule being ignored for applications by kubuntu wayland?

Tags: dual-boot, kubuntu, kde, wayland, system-settings

I am currently dual booting windows 11 and kubutnu(wayland). Recently I changed the scale to 120% because in wayland, the UI was just too tiny too read. So I was trying to resize the system settings application but it was locked beyond a certain point(1224 * 846 size to be exact) and I wasn't able to minimize it as necessary. So I specified a minimum windows rule of 100 * 100 but it didn't have any effect whatsoever. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: From my experience (I don't know why), multiples of 25 work better with fractional scaling in general. You can try 125% fractional scaling. But that is unlikely to help with resizing the window.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce this. Certain apps can have app specific minimum window size. With so many options, System settings will be almost unusable if resized to 100x100. This is probably an intended feature rather than a bug.

Comment: Well as it is currently, the settings app takes up about 90 percent of the screen. Is there any work around to this?